# VB.NET Spaces in display value

Tags: vb.net

Currently this code display's these items in a listbox but the values are dead cramped is there anyway to space these values out?

Here is the code

Any help would be appreciated thanks

```
    While rs.Read
                Dim DisplayValue As String = rs("RentalID") & " " & rs("DateOfHire") & " (" & rs("DateOfReturn") & ")" & " (" & rs("CarID") & ")"

                Dim RentalItem As New Listboxdata(DisplayValue, rs("CustomerID"))
                lstCurrentRentals.Items.Add(RentalItem)
```

Comment: what is rs.Read?

Comment: I believe its part of the OleDbDatareader function

Comment: You could add more space between the values, but it would probably be better to use a `ListView` or `DataGridView` instead and they will allow for sizing / sorting and other useful features.

Comment: How do you add more space between the values?

Comment: as said by Andrew, if you are taking data from DB i suggest you to use DataGridView

Comment: As a note, the `ListBox` control can expand TabStops (to set a pixel distance between text pieces). See [ListBox.UseTabStops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.usetabstops?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.UseTabStops);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2)).

Comment: A Class would not only store related data together as the proper type, but it would allow you to control the default display.  A DGV would be a much more sensible choice though...and easier to use